# Burninate [andriod] misspelled

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Seems to be a misspelling of [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andriod

Comment: As the tag is not used anymore it will be automatically removed within 24h.

Comment: There's no need to make a meta post for small tags (especially typos). Just fix them with an edit

Comment: /me hurries up and posts all of the andriod-related questions that he has been thinking about posting but never did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has no questions tagged to it, which means that it will be automatically deleted overnight.

Whose overnight I am not sure. So give it 24 hours.

Comment: If memory serves: 0300 UTC.